# Split number into minimum sum components

Tags: optimization, summation, linear-programming

I was wondering if there is an analytical solution for the following optimization problem?

We have a given real number say $k$. It is needed to split $k$ into minimum number of real components, so sum of the components is equal to $k$. But, each component is equal or greater than given $x$ and equal or less than given $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given $k$, we can bound the minimum number of components $N^*$ as follows:

$N^*\geq\lceil \frac{k}{y}\rceil$ and $N^*\leq\lceil \frac{k}{y}\rceil$

We'd like to use as many components of size $y$ as possible, but ensuring that the last component is $\geq x$. There are several possibilities:

1. $k<x$: No feasible solution exists.
2. $x\leq k \leq y$: Trivially requires 1 component.
3. $k>y$: Let $c=\lfloor \frac{k}{y}\rfloor$ and $d=k-cy$. If $0<d<x$ then make the last component equal $x$ and the second to last equal $y-x+d$. The rest of the components will equal $y$. If $d=0$, then you simply use $c$ as your minimum number of components.

Comment: Thanks for your correct answer. But, I was wondering what is the role of $r$?

Comment: @ebrahim oops...it does nothing. Ill get rid of it...was from a different version of the algorithm.